# Angular Material datepicker not pre-filling value from Laravel API response

Tags: mysql, angular, laravel, angular-material

I have an Angular Material date picker field in a form.
The form is connected to an API endpoint built with Laravel.
When I select a date in the "create booking" view and POST the form to the endpoint everything works, the date is correctly saved to the database.
However when I load the form and make a GET request and bind the response to the form in the "edit booking" view, the field is NOT pre-filled with the date time.

Here is my date picker field:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="datePicker" placeholder="Booking date" [ngModel]="booking?.date" name="date" required>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="datePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #datePicker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Here is my JSON response:

```
{
    "id": 23,
    "consultant_id": 1669,
    "teacher_id": null,
    "school_id": 6,
    "date": "2018-11-26 00:00:00"
}
```

Here is my component file:

```
export class BookingEditComponent implements OnInit {
    public loading: boolean = false;
    public booking: any;
    public booking_id: number;

constructor(
    private bookingService: BookingService,
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.booking_id = +params['booking_id'];
        this.getBooking(this.booking_id);
    })
}

public getBooking(booking_id: number): void {
    this.bookingService
        .getBooking(booking_id)
        .subscribe(booking => this.booking = booking);
}

public updateBooking(form: any): void {
    var item = form.value;
    this.bookingService
        .updateBooking(this.booking_id, item)
        .subscribe();
}
```

Comment: Add your ts and response json as well.

Comment: just check if you are able to bind other field like `id` in `input box`.

Comment: I think you need to transform the date into a Date object. You can do this by using Moment.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<mat-form-field>
 <input matInput [matDatepicker]="datePicker" placeholder="Booking date" [ngModel]="booking?.date" name="date" required>
 <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="datePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
 <mat-datepicker #datePicker [startAt]="startDate"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

file.ts

```
startDate;

public getBooking(booking_id: number): void {
this.bookingService
    .getBooking(booking_id)
    .subscribe(booking => {
      this.booking = booking
      startDate = new Date(booking.date);
    };
}
```

found in the https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples under the "Datepicker start date"